# Sum of parallel chords given fixed spacing between chords

Tags: summation, circles

We manufacture circular things that have parallel lines across them, evenly spaced. Someone drew a picture here https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LPtM.png though we don't have a chord through the center.

How to sum the lengths of all the parallel chords given radius and the fixed perpendicular distance between chords?

Presently, I use the chord formula based upon perpendicular distance from center:
$2({\sqrt(r^2-h^2)}$, h is perpendicular distance from center

In Excel, I have cell for r and cells for h and enough cells containing the chord formula, and finally the sum.

How to get the sum of all these chords given r, h?

Additional point: We do not ever have a chord passing through the center. In other words, there are always and even number of chords. This defines the position of the first chord.

Example:

r = 30 (it's meters, by the way, these things are huge)

h = 1

So the first chord from center is $h/2 = 0.5$ perpendicularly from center. Its length is:
$2({\sqrt(30^2-0.5^2)} = 29.17$

The next chord is h further away from center, ie $0.5 + h = 1.5$
Its length:
$2({\sqrt(30^2-1.5^2)} = 28.95$

Follow up question: what is the Excel formula (if it even possible with normal Excel formulas)?

Thanks so much for reading even if you do not reply!

Wish I could add tags: sum parallel chords, but not allowed.

Questions here that sound similar but do not fit:

[Sum and average length of chords](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/567796/sum-and-average-length-of-chords/568815)

[Circle Chord Length Given other Chord](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1159117/circle-chord-length-given-other-chord)

[Sum and average length of constrained chords](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2351724/sum-and-average-length-of-constrained-chords)

Comment: If it is helpful there are calculators such as: `https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lejeoyuo81` which can compute summations directly.

Comment: Thanks! That looks useful in some situations though in this case I need it offline for numerous permutations.

Comment: Can anyone suggest another forum where this would be appropriate? Have I expressed the question clearly?